# Font-Face not working on Tumblr

Tags: fonts, tumblr

I applied this codes on [this blog](http://cyruspetrillo.tumblr.com) and the font isn't working on the sidebar titles.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gothambold1';
    src: url('http://pllfans.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/gothambold1.eot');
    src: local('gothambold1'), url('http://pllfans.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/gothambold1.woff') format('woff'), url('http://pllfans.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/gothambold1.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.sidebartitle {
    padding-bottom:13px;
    font-size:21px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-right:-30px;
    padding:30px;
    font-family: 'gothambold1' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a base64 encoding of the font and add it to the @font-face declaration.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'gothambold1';
src: url('http://linktofontface.eot');
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'gothambold1';
src: url(data:font/ttf;base64,[insert-encode-here]) format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

More explanation here: http://nutty-themes.tumblr.com/post/97597308612/an-ongoing-tutorial-series-for-those-who-already